# Questions about forbidden software

Tags: discussion

Should these be allowed?  This [question about the hypothetical zoom bot](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/best-zoom-poker-bot-strategy), for example, is talking about creating a tool that is explicitly forbidden by the PokerStars TOS. It could certainly have been phrased in a way that implies an algorithm-centric view rather than explicitly a "I'm gonna create a bot" view, which might have been a little better. The question is way broad, which doesn't help... and the answers are weak, but that's mostly because this isn't an easy problem. And anyone who knows a good answer is unlikely to ever want to share that answer.

Comment: OP could have at least tried to disguise the question.  I sure took zoom as PokerStars.

Answer (score 3):

It may be prohibited by many sites for real money, but it could be used in a bot tournament for example. I agree it couldve been phrased differently, but I cant assume anything as I dont fully know how the creator intends to utilize it.

I dont mind leaving it up. I think its an interesting springboard into other Q's like, how a developer uses their own thought process and tries to code it into strategy. Also, whteher it gathers some insightful, detailed answers... unklikely as it is, maybe it will, I dont know.

Comment: I guess I interpreted "zoom" as the PokerStars brand of fast-action online cash game poker.

Answer (score 0):

In light of [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/8828/3816), I'm leaning towards no, we shouldn't allow questions about using them. I'm not opposed to general questions about writing poker playing software, as I have done some work on one, but when terms like bot or site specific poker variations, like zoom, are mentioned, I think that's when it crosses a line.